# What is the number of ways to rearrange a set of n members into subsets of all possible sizes from 1 to n ?.

Tags: combinatorics

My question is:

What is the number of ways to divide a set of $n$ members into subsets of all possible size.

To be a bit clearer I have an example: 
from the set {A;B;C;D} one can "rearrange" the members into a finite number of unique ways, which are :

{A;B;C;D}

{A}{B}{C}{D}

{A;B;C}{D}

{A;B;D}{C}

{A;C;D}{B}

{C;D;B}{A}

{A;B}{C;D}

{A;C}{B;D}

{A;D}{B;C}

{A;B}{C}{D}

{A;C}{B}{D}

{A;D}{B}{C}

{B;C}{A}{D}

{B;D}{A}{C}

{C;D}{A}{B}

Note that the order of members in each subset and order of subset itself don't matter. (A,B)(C,D) is equivalent to (D,C)(B,A)

I am sure this "object" has a name in combinatorics but I can't figure out how it is called and how to count it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number). They can be calculated using the recurrence relation
$$B_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkB_k.$$